# Why doesn't my truck start, doesn't turn over, no clicks, nothing happens?

Tags: toyota, starting, tacoma

2005 Toyota Tacoma manual tran. First time it's happened was today. I turn the key, nothing. No click. Nothing turns over. When I turn the key the radio cuts out for a split second.. which is usual... right? But it doesn't start. I just kept trying and trying and eventual it all of a sudden worked and started right up. Now I have no experience with cars but what I've read online makes me think it's the ignition switch? Anyone agree or have a better reason?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the battery voltage and cables?

Comment: Sounds like a bad battery, have it tested first.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many things causing this.

I am reluctant to just blame the battery because you said that after repeated tries it starts right up. That would indicate the battery had enough power. But it can't hurt to have it checked anyway, to rule it out.

Here are some common things that could be causing this;

- Ignition switch
- Battery cables
- Starter relay
- Clutch safety switch

With a manual transmission, a very common cause of starting issues is the clutch switch. It is a safety feature mounted above the pedal and when you press the clutch it activates this switch to allow the engine to start.

[image]

A lot of times these become dirty or out of adjustment which causes intermittent starting or no start. This would be the first thing I check. It is a simple switch with two wires, so it can easily be checked with a multi-meter.